# How to clear cookies and cache in jmeter after each iteration?

Tags: caching, jmeter, httpcookie

The scenario is- After logging out from application either i have to close the browser or have to clear the cache in order to login with same user again, else browser will not give me login page and it will directly redirect me to post login.
When i am running my script from jmeter, its failing for 2nd iteration as its not able to find out the login page.
what needs to be done in jmeter for handling this scenario? i have added http cache and cookie manager in test plan.

I already tried
1.JSR223 Post Processor- sampler.getCacheManager().clear()
2.BeanShell PostProcessor- import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
manager.clear(); for all 3 requests of Logout transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is `Same user on each iteration` setting on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level.

[image]

If you untick it - both HTTP Cookie Manager and HTTP Cache Manager will be cleared when a thread (virtual user) starts new iteration. (only applies to Thread Group's iterations, controllers like Loop, Foreach, While, etc. won't be impacted)

---

If you want to proceed with scripting and copy-pasting the code without understanding what it's doing for JSR223 Post Processor the relevant code would be:

```
prev.getCacheManager().clear()
prev.getCookieManager().clear()
```

but make sure to place it **as a child** of the last [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, see [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more information on the impact of placement of JMeter test elements